# Evaluating Sum of Modified Bessel Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, bessel-functions

In deriving some approximate solutions, I've come across the following sum I need to evaluate

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nI_n(\alpha)e^{-n^2\beta},$$

where $I_n$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and $\alpha,\beta>0$ are arbitrary parameters. As far as I've found, there isn't a known closed form for this sum (please let me know if there is), so I've attempted to find a simplified form by expanding in power series:
$$I_n(\alpha)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)^{2m+n}}{m!(n+m)!}$$
$$e^{-n^2\beta}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{n^{2k}\beta^k}{k!}$$

So the sum above can be written as a triple sum of the form
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)^{2m+n}}{m!(n+m)!}(-1)^k\frac{n^{2k}\beta^k}{k!}$$

In an effort to make some progress, I changed the order of summation to attempt to remove the summation over $n$:
$$S=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\beta^k\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)^{2m}}{m!k!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)^nn^{2k}}{(n+m)!}$$

The innermost sum here seems to be a power series of some function evaluated at some multiple of $\alpha$, but I can't seem to find anything that matches. I would appreciate any help on simplifying this sum. I am also interested in the sum

$$S_2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nn^2I_n(\alpha)e^{-n^2\beta},$$

which should be similar to the sum above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E3) integral representation to derive a formula in terms of the Jacobi theta function:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^\pi  {e^{\alpha \cos t} \cos (nt)dt} e^{ - n^2 \beta } } & = \frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^\pi  {e^{\alpha \cos t} \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \cos (nt)e^{ - n^2 \beta } } } \right)dt} \\ & = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_0^\pi  {e^{\alpha \cos t} \left( {1 + \vartheta \left( {\frac{{t + \pi }}{{2\pi }};i\frac{\beta }{\pi }} \right)} \right)dt} .
\end{align*}
Does this help?

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but is there a method to evaluate this integral with high precision?  I am not familiar with the theta function.